# How to check the internet connection in LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx

How can i check the internet connection in libgdx ? I didnt find anything yet. I want to check the connection before the game starts.

Comment: This may "help" you : https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=557

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since one of your tags is android, i think that you want to check for internet connection on a  android phone.

```
 private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
  ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  if (ni == null) {
   // There are no active networks.
   return false;
  } else
   return true;
 }
```

This is the code that you want to add in your android class.

And you also need to add this to your android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

To integrate this stuff into your main project read this

https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/IntegratingAndroidNativeUiElements3TierProjectSetup

Comment: I think this link meight also help: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code It is to to interface with platformcode so he could use different connection checks depending on the platform

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there's nothing to do this in a convenient way, maybe even using platform specific features.

What you might do is use [`Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(...)`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Net.html#sendHttpRequest%28com.badlogic.gdx.Net.HttpRequest,%20com.badlogic.gdx.Net.HttpResponseListener%29) in order to send a "test" request to any of your servers.

You can define a callback here, namely [`Net.HttpResponseListener`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Net.HttpResponseListener.html#failed%28java.lang.Throwable%29). It has a `failed(...)` callback, which states that this might happen in case of a timeout. You could wait for this callback and in case it doesn't happen, assume that there is an internet connection.

Comment: Works likes a charm. This is even better than the Android version.